# Flumes installation on window OS

Tags: flume

Hi I am very new to Flume. I have installed flumes 0.9.3 version and able to start the node in window OS.

But to move forward I need certain basic things. Can any one help me to setup flumes completely?

1. How to setup flumes agent and configure with any source like fileshare or server log
2. How to setup flumes collector
3. How the sink in agent will push the files to collector
4. How to install flumes master and configure with multiple agents and collector
5. How to integrate flumes collectors with HDFS.

Comment: If you are new to Flume, you should be using Flume 1.x (otherwise known as Flume-NG). Flume 0.x is no longer maintained, as has not been worked on in over a year.

Comment: Also, it's quite hard to answer all these questions... Take a look at the [documentation](http://flume.apache.org/FlumeUserGuide.html) and give it a try, then ask specific questions if/when you get stuck.